# Clear Case rebase operation fails

Tags: clearcase, rebase

When I try to 'rebase' my stream in clear case, I get the 2 options : 'Resume rebase' and 'Undo rebase'.
But both of them give me errors. It seems a previous rebase failed and left the stream in a corrupted state.

How to solve this?

I tried stopping and starting ClearCase but no luck.

EDIT: the error is :

```
IDispatch error #14083  
Execution of a hook failed during the action Complete.  It was the ACTION_COMMIT hook   attached to the UCMUtilityActivity "CR00155721".  
The reason for the failure was:  
Trouble communicating with VOB database: "\Alerts_Proj".  
Check database log on VOB host "123yyyyy.com".  
Could not perform requested operation: a UCM/ClearQuest data  
inconsistency may exist:  
ClearQuest "UCMUtilityActivity" record "CR00155721" is linked to a UCM object  
that can not be found.  
Unable to complete the rebase activity in ClearQuest.  
Unable to undo set of integration activity.  
Unable to complete integration.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the errors that you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be deactivating the trigger, but this could be put by the ClearCase-ClearQuest link and not be possible without severing completely that link.

So you can start by checking out this [IBM technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21180957) with your ClearCase administrator:

> This error occurs because the UCM project VOB and associated activities have been removed, ClearQuest is still looking for this information and needs this information to remove the defect.
>
> This issue is the result the ClearCase items being removed before the ClearQuest defects and project.
>
> **Solution**
>
> To resolve this issue perform the following to fix the Activity so it can be deleted:
>
> - Browse to the ClearCase utils directory:

```
    c:\program files\rational\clearcase\etc\utils
```

> - Run the following command from a command prompt:
>   Note: This command cannot be performed in the GUI

```
squid_patch <DBNAME> -activity  ucm_vob_object ""
```

> Note: It will display an advisory message, but it will change the field in ClearQuest.
>
> - Delete the ClearQuest record.
>   Remove the UCM project with the following command:

```
squid_patch <DBNAME> -project  ucm_vob_object ""
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI I've also seen this happen when the "CQIntSvr11.exe" fails.  It seems to occur when you need to use the application on the same machine with different users (e.g. admin and developer account).

If you kill the process using task manager and then retry the operation the IDispatch 14083 should stop and then you can use your stream again.